# Downloading file error: Cannot convert type

Tags: c#, .net, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm trying to download a file from my DropBox account.

I get an error with
`var task = Task.Run((Func<Task>)Download("", "largetest.mpk", folderName));`

The error:
`Cannot convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' to 'System.Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>`

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 string folderName = @"c:\dropboxTest\test.exe";
var task = Task.Run((Func<Task>)Download("", "largetest.mpk", folderName));
task.Wait();
}
async Task Download(string folder, string targetfile, string localPath)
    {
        var dbx = new DropboxClient(Form1.api);
        var response = await dbx.Files.DownloadAsync(folder + "/" + targetfile);
        ulong fileSize = response.Response.Size;
        const int bufferSize = 1024 * 1024;
        var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        string folderName = @"C:\dropboxTest\teasdfst.exe";
        using (var stream = await response.GetContentAsStreamAsync())
        {
            using (var localfile = new FileStream(folderName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                var length = stream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                while (length > 0)
                {
                    localfile.Write(buffer, 0, length);
                   // Console.WriteLine(localfile.);
                    var percentage = 100 * (ulong)localfile.Length / fileSize;
                    // Update progress bar with the percentage.
                    // progressBar.Value = (int)percentage
                    //Console.WriteLine(percentage);
                    length = stream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just make the event handler `async` and `await` `Download` in it. You don't need `Task.Run` at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write your function like this

```
void Download(string folder, string targetfile, string localPath)
{
    var dbx = new DropboxClient(Form1.api);
    var response = dbx.Files.Download(folder + "/" + targetfile);
    ulong fileSize = response.Response.Size;
    const int bufferSize = 1024 * 1024;
    var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    string folderName = @"C:\dropboxTest\teasdfst.exe";
    using (var stream = response.GetContentAsStream())
    {
        using (var localfile = new FileStream(folderName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            var length = stream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            while (length > 0)
            {
                localfile.Write(buffer, 0, length);
               // Console.WriteLine(localfile.);
                var percentage = 100 * (ulong)localfile.Length / fileSize;
                // Update progress bar with the percentage.
                // progressBar.Value = (int)percentage
                //Console.WriteLine(percentage);
                length = stream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then call with `Task.Run` like below

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string folderName = @"c:\dropboxTest\test.exe";
    var task = Task.Run(() => Download("", "largetest.mpk", folderName));
    task.Wait(); // remove this if you don't want to block UI thread.
}
```

Hope this helps !!

Comment: This will block the UI thread. Also, there is no reason to call `Task.Run` at all and making `Download` a void method is the wrong thing to do.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tried your code and I had to change the method to `async Task DownloadAsync(string folder, string targetfile, string localPath)` and it works but it locks you the application so nothing works until the download finishes.

Comment: @natehome, for this you need to remove the task.Wait() statement.

Comment: @AluanHaddad, as per OP's question sample, I thought he wants to wait until task executes. Updated my answer against it.

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan comment is fine but there is no point in blocking the UI thread. Also, this code won't compile. The method signature and modifiers in the OP are correct.

Comment: @AluanHaddad, yes there is no point of blocking UI thread and hence updated my answer with explanation. In regards with method signature, modifiers and compile error not sure what you are referring as OP was able to run this code but having the issue of UI block which I already explained.

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan it is simple. `void Download(...)` is invalid because it `await`s. `async Task Download(...)` is what you want.

Comment: @AluanHaddad, thanks for pointing this out. Corrected the method as per the needful.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to do all of that. No conversions, no casts, no `Task.Run`.

Just write

```
const string folderName = @"c:\dropboxTest\test";

private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Download("", "largetest.mpk", folderName);
}
```

Note that we directly await the method call. Note how the call to `Task.Wait` has been removed.

Note that *except* in the case of event handlers, which need to be `void` methods, `async` methods should `return` `Task` objects. This is very important, especially for proper exception handling. This is the only case where `async void` is proper.

Your `Download` method, which should be renamed to `DownloadAsync` by convention, already has the proper return type `Task` and should not be changed in that regard.